# jQuery Draggable Area (to drag with, not in)

Tags: jquery, draggable

I'm wondering how to drag around a div (#container) using a different div (child div specifically #dragBar).  Is there a parameter in the .draggable() function that could set a one div to drag around another?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, try using the [`handle`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle) option; for example:

```
$("yourElement").draggable({"handle": "otherElement"});
```

Comment: BAM! That's the one. Thank you.  I have to wait 7 minutes to give you the check mark, but it's coming.

Comment: @Jascha No problem, enjoy. :)